# items from a tree view

Tags: vb.net

How do I display Items that are Checked from a treeView in a listBox using VB?

Comment: Winforms, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it's winforms:

```
ListView1.Items.Clear()
For Each node As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
    If node.Checked Then
         ListView1.Items.Add(node.Text)
    End If
Next
```

Edit: Code for calling recursive method:

```
ListView1.Items.Clear()
AddToList(TreeView1.Nodes)
```

Recursive method:

```
private sub AddToList(nodes as TreeNodeCollection)
  For Each node As TreeNode In nodes
    If node.Checked Then
      ListView1.Items.Add(node.Text)
      AddToList(node.Nodes)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

You'd have to adjust this if you want them to appear in a certain order or anything like that. Can't remember if you might also have to have a check for 'If nodes is nothing Then return' at the beginning of the 'AddToList' method.

Comment: Thanks!!! It pulled my information sucessfully. Would I intergrate my subfolders and files in the same code?

Comment: @jpavlov: If you just want everything on the same level, just look at my adjusted answer.